# javassist.NotFoundException error in Spring framework project using Javassist - Need help knowing how to set classpath and class name

Tags: java, spring-mvc, classpath, javassist

I'm using javassist on a model: com.project.model.Model
I've tried various combinations of how the Strings should be formatted for the ClassPath and the CtClass, but to no avail.

```
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    String setClassPath = "/com/project/model/";
    pool.insertClassPath(setClassPath);
    CtClass ctClass = pool.get("Model.java");
```

How should these Strings be formatted?  I am using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1, JVM 1.7, spring-webmvc 3.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out by grabbing the classpath of the an instance of Model:

```
Model model = new Model();
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
ClassClassPath ccpath = new ClassClassPath(model.getClass());
pool.insertClassPath(ccpath);
CtClass ctClass = pool.get("com.project.Model");
```

Comment: You just concluded two days of hair tearing search. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Adding current classloader will solve the problem. It couldn't find the classes because Javaassist and Tomcat maintain different classloader.

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
```